# 32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, x86-64, linker-errors, relocation

64 bit Linux uses the small memory model by default, which puts all code and static data below the 2GB address limit. This makes sure that you can use 32-bit absolute addresses. Older versions of gcc use 32-bit absolute addresses for static arrays in order to save an extra instruction for relative address calculation. However, this no longer works. If I try to make a 32-bit absolute address in assembly, I get the linker error:
"relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC".
This error message is misleading, of course, because I am not making a shared object and -fPIC doesn't help.
What I have found out so far is this: gcc version 4.8.5 uses 32-bit absolute addresses for static arrays, gcc version 6.3.0 doesn't. version 5 probably doesn't either. The linker in binutils 2.24 allows 32-bit absolute addresses, verson 2.28 does not.

The consequence of this change is that old libraries have to be recompiled and legacy assembly code is broken.

Now I want to ask: When was this change made? Is it documented somewhere? And is there a linker option that makes it accept 32-bit absolute addresses?

Comment: Related: [What do R\_X86\_64\_32S and R\_X86\_64\_64 relocation mean?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6093547) for more background.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463150/what-is-the-fpie-option-for-position-independent-executables-in-gcc-and-ld

Answer (score 70):

Your distro configured gcc with `--enable-default-pie`, so it's making position-independent executables by default, (allowing for ASLR of the executable as well as libraries).  Most distros are doing that, these days.

You actually *are* making a shared object: PIE executables are sort of a hack using a shared object with an entry-point.  The dynamic linker already supported this, and ASLR is nice for security, so this was the easiest way to implement ASLR for executables.

32-bit absolute relocations aren't allowed in an ELF shared object; that would stop them from being loaded outside the low 2GiB (for sign-extended 32-bit addresses).  64-bit absolute addresses are allowed, but generally you only want that for jump tables or other static data, not as part of instructions.<sup>1</sup>

The `recompile with -fPIC` part of the error message is bogus for hand-written asm; it's written for the case of people compiling with `gcc -c` and then trying to link with `gcc -shared -o foo.so  *.o`, with a gcc where `-fPIE` is *not* the default.  The error message should probably change because many people are running into this error when linking hand-written asm.

The correct way to interpret `recompile with -fPIC` is "*make new asm that's PIE compatible*", either with a compiler from C source or by hand if your source is asm.

---

#### How to use RIP-relative addressing: basics

Always use RIP-relative addressing for simple cases where there's no downside.  See also footnote 1 below and [this answer for syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745872/how-do-rip-relative-variable-references-like-rip-a-in-x86-64-gas-intel-sy).    Only consider using absolute addressing when it's actually helpful for code-size instead of harmful. e.g. **NASM `default rel`** at the top of your file.

**AT&T `foo(%rip)`** or in GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` use `[rip + foo]`.

---

## Disable PIE mode to make 32-bit absolute addressing work

**Use `gcc -fno-pie -no-pie` to override this back to the old behaviour.**  `-no-pie` is the linker option, [`-fno-pie` is the code-gen option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html).  With only `-fno-pie`, gcc will make code like `mov eax, offset .LC0` that doesn't link with the still-enabled `-pie`.

(**clang** can have PIE enabled by default, too: use **`clang -fno-pie -nopie`**.  A [July 2017 patch](https://reviews.llvm.org/D35462) made `-no-pie` an alias for `-nopie`, for compat with gcc, but clang4.0.1 doesn't have it.)

---

#### Performance cost of PIE for 64-bit (minor) or 32-bit code (major)

**With only `-no-pie`, (but still `-fpie`) compiler-generated code (from C or C++ sources) will be slightly slower and larger than necessary**, but will still be linked into a position-dependent executable which won't benefit from ASLR.  **"Too much PIE is bad for performance" [reports an average slowdown of 3% for x86-64 on SPEC CPU2006](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41697/why-doesnt-linux-randomize-the-address-of-the-executable-code-segment/42641#42641)** (I don't have a copy of the paper so IDK what hardware that was on :/).  But in 32-bit code, the average slowdown is 10%, worst-case 25% (on SPEC CPU2006).

The penalty for PIE executables is mostly for stuff like indexing static arrays, as Agner describes in the question, where using a static address as a 32-bit immediate or as part of a `[disp32 + index*4]` addressing mode saves instructions and registers vs. a RIP-relative LEA to get an address into a register.  Also 5-byte `mov r32, imm32` instead of 7-byte `lea r64, [rel symbol]` for getting a static address into a register is nice for passing the address of a string literal or other static data to a function.

`-fPIE` still assumes no symbol-interposition for global variables / functions, unlike `-fPIC` for shared libraries which have to go through the GOT to access globals (which is yet another reason to use `static` for any variables that can be limited to file scope instead of global).   See [The sorry state of dynamic libraries on Linux](https://web.archive.org/web/20171111043629/http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/).

Thus `-fPIE` is much less bad than `-fPIC` for 64-bit code, but still **bad for 32-bit because RIP-relative addressing isn't available**.  See [some examples on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A//+godbolt+doesn!%27t+build+gcc+with+--enable-default-pie%0A//+so+-fno-pie+-no-pie+is+the+default.%0A%0A//+-fPIE+mostly+just+costs+you+RIP-relative+LEA%0A//+-fPIC+is+even+more+expensive+than+-fPIE+for+global+vars,%0A//++requiring+a+load+to+get+the+address+of+a+global%0A%0A%0A//__attribute__((weak))+extern+int+ext%3B++//+PIE+can!%27t+assume+its+definition+wins,+so+the+address+isn!%27t+a+link-time+constant+anymore%0A%0A//+overhead+only+with+PIC.++RIP-relative+is+already+good+for+static+data%0A//+static++//+would+remove+PIC+overhead%0A++int+ext+%3D+1%3B%0Aint*+scalar_global(void)+%7B%0A++ext+%3D+123%3B%0A++//return+%26ext%3B++//+minor+PIC/PIE+overhead%0A++return+NULL%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+overhead+with+PIE,+more+overhead+with+PIC+(dependent+load)%0A//+no-pic+can+use+the+address+as+a+disp32+for+an+indexed+addressing+mode%0Aint+arr%5B1024%5D%3B%0Aint+fetch(long+idx)+%7B%0A++return+arr%5Bidx%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+PIE+and+PIC+both+use+a+RIP-relative+LEA+for+the+string+literal%0A//+instead+of+mov-immediate+(smaller+and+runs+on+more+ports)%0A//+-fno-plt+works+the+same+for+no-pie,+pie,+and+pic%0A//+Even+no-pie+executables+still+call+shared+libs+through+the+PLT+by+default%0Avoid+call_sharedlib(void)+%7B%0A++puts(%22hello%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A//+jmp+puts++turns+into+puts@PLT+when+the+linker+finds%0A//+the+puts+symbol+in+libc.so+instead+of+a+static+library.%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:34.28344416186805,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),libs:!(),options:%27-xc+-Wall+-O3++-fno-pie+-no-pie%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),libs:!(),options:%27-xc+-std%3Dc99+-O3+-fPIE+-no-pie%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.18220551902322,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:33.21998747260075,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),libs:!(),options:%27-xc+-Wall+-O3++-fPIC%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:32.49656836553122,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),libs:!(),options:%27-xc+-Wall+-O3++-fno-plt+-fPIC%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%234)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:32.49656836553122,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).  On average, `-fPIE` has a very small performance / code-size downside in 64-bit code.  The worst case for a specific loop might only be a few %.  But 32-bit PIE can be much worse.

None of these `-f` code-gen options make any difference when just linking,
or when assembling `.S` hand-written asm.  `gcc -fno-pie -no-pie -O3 main.c nasm_output.o` is a case where you want both options.

---

#### Checking your GCC config

**If your GCC was configured this way, `gcc -v |& grep -o -e '[^ ]*pie'`  prints `--enable-default-pie`**.  Support for this config option was added to gcc in [early 2015](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-01/msg00701.html).  Ubuntu enabled it in 16.10, and Debian around the same time in gcc `6.2.0-7` (leading to kernel build errors: https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/10/21/904).

Related: [Build compressed x86 kernels as PIE](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/10/20/141) was also affected by the changed default.

[Why doesn't Linux randomize the address of the executable code segment?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41697/why-doesnt-linux-randomize-the-address-of-the-executable-code-segment) is an older question about why it wasn't the default earlier, or was only enabled for a few packages on older Ubuntu before it was enabled across the board.

---

Note that **`ld` itself didn't change its default**.  It still works normally (at least on Arch Linux with binutils 2.28).  The change is that `gcc` defaults to passing `-pie` as a linker option, unless you explicitly use `-static` or `-no-pie`.

In a NASM source file, I used `a32 mov eax, [abs buf]` to get an absolute address.  (I was testing if the 6-byte way to encode small absolute addresses (address-size + mov eax,moffs: `67 a1 40 f1 60 00`) has an LCP stall on Intel CPUs.  [It does](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34733#c3).)

```
nasm -felf64 -Worphan-labels -g -Fdwarf testloop.asm &&
ld -o testloop testloop.o              # works: static executable

gcc -v -nostdlib testloop.o            # doesn't work
...
..../collect2  ... -pie ...
/usr/bin/ld: testloop.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

gcc -v -no-pie -nostdlib testloop.o    # works
gcc -v -static -nostdlib testloop.o    # also works: -static implies -no-pie
```

GCC can also make a "static PIE" with `-static-pie`; ASLRed by no dynamic libraries or ELF interpreter.  Not the same thing as `-static -pie` - those conflict with each other (you get a static non-PIE) although [it might possibly get changed](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2018-01/msg00255.html).

related: [building static / dynamic executables with/without libc, defining `_start` or `main`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649).

---

#### Checking if an existing executable is PIE or not

This has also been asked at: [How to test whether a Linux binary was compiled as position independent code?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89211/test-whether-linux-binary-is-compiled-as-position-independent-code)

`file` and `readelf` say that PIEs are "shared objects", not ELF executables.  ELF-type EXEC can't be PIE.

```
$ gcc -fno-pie  -no-pie -O3 hello.c
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ...

$ gcc -O3 hello.c
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ...

 ## Or with a more recent version of file:
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ...
```

gcc `-static-pie` is a special thing that GCC doesn't do by default, even with `-nostdlib`.  It shows up as `LSB pie executable`, `dynamically linked` with current versions of `file`. (See [What's the difference between "statically linked" and "not a dynamic executable" from Linux ldd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553723/whats-the-difference-between-statically-linked-and-not-a-dynamic-executable)).  It has ELF-type DYN, but `readelf` shows no `.interp`, and `ldd` will tell you it's statically linked.  GDB `starti` and `/proc/maps` confirms that execution starts at the top of its `_start`, not in an ELF interpreter.

---

---

**Semi-related** (but not really): another recent gcc feature is **`gcc -fno-plt`**.  Finally calls into shared libraries can be just `call [rip + symbol@GOTPCREL]` (AT&T `call *puts@GOTPCREL(%rip)`), with no PLT trampoline.

The NASM version of this is `call [rel puts wrt ..got]`
as an alternative to `call puts wrt ..plt`.  See [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126328/cant-call-c-standard-library-function-on-64-bit-linux-from-assembly-yasm-code).  This works in a PIE or non-PIE, and avoids having the linker build a PLT stub for you.

Some distros have started enabling it.  It also avoids needing writeable + executable memory pages so it's good for security against code-injection.  (I think modern PLT implementation's don't need that either, just updating a GOT pointer not rewriting a `jmp rel32` instruction, so there might not be a security difference.)

It's a significant speedup for programs that make a lot of shared-library calls, e.g. x86-64 `clang -O2 -g` compiling tramp3d goes from 41.6s to 36.8s on whatever hardware [the patch author tested on](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-05/msg00225.html).  (clang is maybe a worst-case scenario for shared library calls, making lots of calls to small LLVM library functions.)

It does require early binding instead of lazy dynamic linking, so it's slower for big programs that exit right away.  (e.g. `clang --version` or compiling `hello.c`).  This slowdown could be reduced with prelink, apparently.

This doesn't remove the GOT overhead for external variables in shared library PIC code, though.  (See the godbolt link above).

---

#### Footnote 1: 64-bit absolute

64-bit absolute addresses actually are allowed in Linux ELF shared objects, with [text relocations](https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2016/01/textrels-text-relocations-and-their-impact-on-hardening-techniques/) to allow loading at different addresses (ASLR and shared libraries).  This allows you to have jump tables in `section .rodata`, or `static const int *foo = &bar;` without a runtime initializer.

So `mov rdi, qword msg` works (NASM/YASM syntax for 10-byte [`mov r64, imm64`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html), aka AT&T syntax `movabs`, the only instruction which can use a 64-bit immediate).  But that's larger and usually slower than **`lea rdi, [rel msg]`**, which is what you should use if you decide not to disable `-pie`.  A 64-bit immediate is slower to fetch from the uop cache on Sandybridge-family CPUs, according to [Agner Fog's microarch pdf](http://agner.org/optimize/).  (Yes, the same person who asked this question. :)

You can use NASM's `default rel` instead of specifying it in every `[rel symbol]` addressing mode.  See also [Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM Accessing Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300844/mach-o-64-bit-format-does-not-support-32-bit-absolute-addresses-nasm-accessing) for some more description of avoiding 32-bit absolute addressing.  OS X can't use 32-bit addresses at all, so RIP-relative addressing is the best way there, too.

**In position-dependent code (`-no-pie`), you should use `mov edi, msg`** when you want an address in a register; 5-byte `mov r32, imm32` is even smaller than RIP-relative LEA, and more execution ports can run it.

Comment: For `-m32` this is really bad, as it wastes a precious register to hold the PC. My 64-bit distribution has the flag enabled aswell, so the `-m32` too uses it.

Comment: Thanks, this finally explains why so many crappy build systems started breaking some time back. Do you understand why `--enable-default-pie` was only enabled in Ubuntu 16.10 and not earlier? Yes, it was only added on GCC 5, but then why only GCC 5? Is it because computers got fast enough that people stopped caring about the perf loss, or is it some new CPU / kernel feature that made things more efficient? The following hardening pages didn't help me much: https://wiki.debian.org/Hardening/PIEByDefaultTransition | https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SteveBeattie/PIENotes

Comment: @CiroSantilli包子露宪六四事件法轮功: Thanks for the edits.  I think more that everyone was finally convinced of the security benefit, and decided to risk build breakage from changing the default.  (The perf benefit is really very small on average, for 64-bit.)  I wasn't following any mailing list discussion about it, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes Can an executable that wasn't compiled as  PIC make use of ASLR?

Comment: @Trey: For 32-bit code only, yes you can compile without `-fPIE` but still link with `-pie`, I think.  Then you get runtime relocations for all the 32-bit absolute addresses embedded all over the place in the code.  That doesn't work in 64-bit mode because compilers correctly choose efficient 32-bit absolute immediates and disp32 addressing modes when you compile without `-fPIE`, and that prevents linking.  64-bit absolute addresses can get runtime relocation, but you'll only find that in jump tables or `static int *foo = &bar` static data; code won't use `mov r64, imm64` for addresses.

Comment: @Trey: if you're asking if a non-PIE executable can use ASLR, the answer is no (except for stack / heap ASLR, of course).  The kernel's ELF program loader will always respect the base address in the ELF metadata for the code / data / BSS segments for a non-PIE executable.

Comment: The PLT trampoline will make it possible to reuse cached prediction information, `-fno-plt` will cause each call site to need separate prediction information. Are you sure `fno-plt` is better?

Comment: @doug65536: That's an interesting point, but IIRC clang benchmarks (of clang itself which makes a lot of calls into LLVM libraries) showed a significant speed.  Remember that even direct calls need prediction to avoid stalling instruction fetch.  Especially in modern x86 with buffers between fetch, finding instruction boundaries, and then full decode pipeline stages, decode happens quite a few cycles after the call target is fetched on a correct prediction.  [Slow jmp-instruction](//stackoverflow.com/q/38811901) explains more: even a `jmp +0` needs a BTB entry.

Comment: @JL2210: thanks, replaced with a wayback machine link.  Still a useful write-up that describes how the pieces fit together.  (Before `-fno-plt` was added, which helps some)

Comment: "Static executables can't be PIE." is outdated. Search up static-pie on Google.

Comment: @JL2210: Interesting.  `gcc -static-pie` does apparently work.  The ELF type is still `DYN` (shared object), but there's no `.interp` header; it seems that execution really does start at the top of its `_start`, not in an ELF interpreter ld.so like you get from execve on a normal PIE.  `file` incorrectly(?) says it's dynamically linked.

Comment: It's a relatively new invention. IIRC, glibc 2.27 was the first version to implement it. That's probably why `file` is confused.

Comment: @JL2210 It needs glibc support?  I guess for special CRT code.  Anyway, updated my answer; I think I caught both places where I needed to address that possibility, but you've probably read through this answer more recently than I have.  LMK if there's another spot my edit missed; thanks.